# import error with numpy and matplotlib in Sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I think I have tried anything that I could find on the internet like

```
pip install numpy
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

among others....

However, Sublime Text 3 keeps telling that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

ImportError: No module named numpy
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Same with other packages such as `matplotlib`

From the beginning I installed Sublime Text 3, nothing else.

Can anybody help me about how to manage installed packages in Sublime Text 3 with Ubuntu?

Comment: Does Sublime use Python 2 or Python 3? Because the first command likely installs numpy for Python 2, while the second one install it for Python 3.

Comment: How come you need `sudo` for `apt-get`, but not when using `pip`?

Comment: i didnt know that......using python 3.3, and I do not why, but `pip install numpy` somehow installs numpy, but Sublime does not recognize it

Comment: It is likely that your system default python is Python 2, not 3, and sublime picks up the default python.

Comment: it's unclear whether you are trying to execute python code through a sublime terminal emulator such as REPL or if you are developing a sublime package. In the second case, note that "Sublime Text 3 comes with its own Python interpreter that’s separate from your system’s Python interpreter (if available)." [ST doc](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html), which means you have to install python modules inside ST's package directory to use them.

Comment: In your Python program, run `import sys; print(sys.version, sys.executable)`. What is the output?

Comment: Hi MattDMo, here you have the output you asked for `>>> print(sys.version, sys.executable)
3.3.3 (default, Dec 19 2013, 14:11:33) 
[GCC 4.7.2] python3` I am thinking about deleting Sublime Text 3 and install again a clean copy, but I would like to know that standard, or the correct way to install python packages for Sublime Text 3